# Perforce:Need some introduction on Perforce streams

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce streams. I have gone though some docs over net and not clearly understood what is the main use of perforce streams.
Can any one please help me giving brief intro on perforce streams. what is the main purpose ? when it is useful ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer this question if you gave some hint of your context -- do you already understand the general concepts of branching and merging as they're used in other tools, or better yet, are you already familiar with how branching works in Perforce without streams?  If so I could give you some specifics on what the benefits of streams are relative to manually managing branch and client views.

For this answer though I'm going to assume you're new to branching in general and will simply direct you to the 2006 Google Tech Talk "The Flow of Change", which was given by Laura Wingerd, one of the chief architects of Perforce streams.  This is from about 5 years before streams were actually implemented in Perforce (the 2011.1 release), but the core ideas around what it means to manage the flow of change between variants of software are all there.  Hopefully with the additional context of the stream docs you've already read it'll be more clear why this is useful in the real world.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ-CpGsCpM0

Comment: @ Sam Stafford , Thanks for your reply. i am aware of branching and merging concepts in perforce. But i want to know more on streams what is the purpose of it? By using this streams what are the advantages ? it would be great if you give some example..

Comment: what is main difference between branch and stream? What is advantages of stream over branch in perforce.

Comment: I'll leave this answer up for others searching for this question who don't have that context.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're already familiar with branching in Perforce, you're aware that a branch can be any arbitrary collection of files, managed by two types of view:

1. One or more client views, which define the set of files you need to map to your workspace in order to sync the branch
2. One or more branch views, which define how to merge changes between this branch and other branches.  (Even if you don't define permanent branch specs, if you run `p4 integrate src... dst...` that's an ad hoc branch view.)

The main purpose of streams from a technical standpoint is to eliminate the work of maintaining these views.  With "classic" Perforce branching, you might declare the file path `//depot/main/...` is your mainline and `//depot/rel1/...` is your `rel1` release branch, and then define views like this:

```
Branch: rel1
View:
     //depot/main/... //depot/rel1/...

Client: main-ws
View:
    //depot/main/... //main-ws/...

Client: rel1-ws
View:
    //depot/rel1/... //rel1-ws/...
```

If you wanted to have one workspace and switch between the two branches you'd do something like:

```
p4 client -t rel1-ws
p4 sync
(do work in rel1)
p4 submit
p4 client -t main-ws
p4 sync
p4 integ -r -b rel1
```

This is a very simple example of course -- if you decide you want to unmap some files from the branch, then you have to make that change in both client specs and possibly the branch view, if you create more branches that's more client specs and more branch specs, etc.

---

With streams the same simple two-branch setup is represented by two streams:

```
Stream: //depot/main
Parent: none
Type: mainline
Paths:
    share ...

Stream: //depot/rel1
Parent: //depot/main
Type: release
Paths:
    share ...
```

To do work in both streams you'd do:

```
p4 switch rel1
(do work in rel1)
p4 submit
p4 switch main
p4 merge --from rel1
```

All tasks around managing branch and client views are handled automatically -- the `switch` command generates a client view appropriate to the named stream and syncs it (it also shelves your work in progress, or optionally relocates it to the new stream similar to a `git checkout` command), and the `merge` command generates a branch view that maps between the current stream and the named source stream.

More complex views are also handled; for example, if you want to ignore all `.o` files in all workspaces associated with either of these streams, just add this to the `//depot/main` stream:

```
Ignored:
    .o
```

This is automatically inherited by all child streams and is reflected in all automatically generated client and branch views (it's like adding a `-//depot/branch/....o //client/...` line to all your client views at once).

There's a lot more that you can do with stream definitions but hopefully that gives you the general idea -- the point is to take all the work that people do to manage views associated with codelines and centralize/automate it for ease of use, as well as provide nice syntactic sugar like `p4 switch` and `p4 merge --from`.

Comment: @ Sam Stafford, Thanks alot :) it really helps. Doubt: if we want to work with streams parent and child streams should have same folder structure? I.e 'main' branch has A,B,C folders and 'private' branch which is child of main stream should also have A,B,C for mandatory  or we can have our views as our wish in child stream? And is there any advantage of space consumption with using streams?

Comment: @ Sam Stafford,Currently we are in classic perforce and we want to move our project to perforce streams. Do we need to address any thing before doing that ?

Comment: It's generally recommended that you start a new project in streams rather than try to migrate an existing project -- there isn't a user-friendly migration path (you can do it but you need to have a really solid understanding of how Perforce's data model works or have assistance from someone who does).

Streams do let you filter/remap the relationships between parent and child streams and this can indirectly result in space savings.  I'd recommend studying stream capabilities in more detail and thinking about how they might relate to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the update Sam :) if we move the classic depot to perforce streams history of those files will also come to streams ?  Streams follow parent child relation ship right ? it mean both parent branch and child branch should have same hierarchy (i.e both branches should have same folder structure) ?In my requirement i just want to create the child stream with only partial content. if i do that it is showing that changes needs to integrate from main..Cant we work by creating child stream with partial content of main (patent) stream? your answer will give me clarity whether to use stream:)

Comment: It will if you do it right, per my earlier caveats.  Good luck!  ;)

Comment: Sam, thanks for your support. I got to know more stuff on streams on perforce.

Comment: I have a requirement to create a child stream which will pick only specific folders from 'mainline'(parent) stream To achieve this i can restrict the view by using 'share/isolate/import' in my paths of view and successfully able to create the child streams which only the code i am interested in.   
But, I have gone through some tutorials on streams and found something on 'lightweight streams' which seems to be related to my requirement.I just want to know is there any limitations on using 'lightweight' streams?

Comment: Yes, there are limitations on using task streams.