# Can we get the changes from classic deport to stream depot in perforce?

Tags: perforce

One question i have, After creating a stream from classic depot(consider it as main branch) we will be working on stream (mainline stream). If suppose when some developer is not aware that streams are in and made check-ins in classic depot mian branch and if we want to get those changes from classic deport to respective mainline 'stream' is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> If suppose when some developer is not aware that streams are in and made check-ins in classic depot mian branch```

Use `p4 protect` to remove `write` access to your main branch if you don't want people submitting to it.  That's ***much*** easier than trying to relocate changes that went to a place they should never have gone to.

Generally speaking, though, if a change is made on the wrong branch/stream, the easiest thing is to merge it to the right one.  You can also `undo` it on the original stream if needed.

Comment: Thanks Same :) we can use the 'p4 protect'. But if we want to get the changes from classic deport branch to stream depot branch is it possible ? Can you please also point me good command line docs working with streams for my reference.

Comment: To get changes from one place to another use `integrate` (or `merge` or `copy`).  https://www.perforce.com/blog/streams-tiny-tutorial

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/sites/default/files/files/2017-11/streams-adoption-guide.pdf
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/chapter.codelines.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing links :) So, your final answer for my question is , it is possible to integrate the changes from classic depot to stream depot right ? :)

Comment: Why would it not be?

Comment: Ohh , then p4 integ/p4 merge will work for integrating the changes from classic to stream deport ? if yes , then its too good :)

Comment: What is the main difference b/w branch and stream in perforce ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623273/perforceneed-some-introduction-on-perforce-streams

Comment: Sam, I tried integrating changes from classic depot to stream depot. Change are integrating but the submission is not happening.  Posted a question for help :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727469/perforce-integration-not-able-to-submit-the-changes